# How to remove the bootloader startup screen on RPi 4 Buster?

Tags: boot, boot-issues, raspbian-buster, bootloader, raspberry-pi-os-buster

When the Raspberry Pi boots, a bootloader info screen (see image below) shows up for about 1 second. I was wondering how I would go about disabling this screen from appearing.

I have tried a couple of guides on how to achieve a quiet boot but seems like this screen shows up no matter what the contents of my `cmdline.txt` and `config.txt` files are.

**My current file contents are:**

```
/boot/cmdline.txt
```

`splash quiet console=serial0,115200 console=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty3 loglevel=3 logo.nologo root=PARTUUID=c356f926-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait`

```
/boot/config.txt
```

`disable_splash=1`

[image: Photo of screen]

Comment: There's no point in anything involving `cmdline.txt` because that is for the linux kernel.

Comment: I recommended you should not remove it because pi is a development board and things can go wrong.

Comment: Your screen shot shows a system that hasn't been able to boot from SDcard or USB device. There's no way to suppress that in just the same way that there's no way to use a system in that state.

Comment: The system does boot after 1 second and works as expected though. Is it possible that the SD card has been corrupted or something similar? Would a corrupt SD card cause this?

Comment: Yea, something is strange here - I have not seen this screen before. I get the white "Press shift for recovery" screen and then the boot sequence starts (silent mode disabled).

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this much more easily by calling:

```
sudo -E rpi-eeprom-config --edit
```

Adding:

```
DISABLE_HDMI=1
```

and Save

For me that works fine.

Answer (score 0):

From the Pi Website...

*The bootloader EEPROM image contains an embedded configuration file to define the boot behaviour (e.g. selecting between SD, network and USB boot).*

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/booteeprom.md

---

That splash screen can only be disabled in the config.txt located in the Bootloader in the EEPROM.

Here's the Steps i used (explained as simply as i can) to disable it.

**STEP1:** log into your Raspberry Pi via Terminal SSH (i used PuTTy) default login is pi .. password is raspberry

**STEP2:** type (or copy'n'paste) this .. **vcgencmd bootloader_version** to display the version and date of the bootloader you are using. eg. mine is Sep  3 2020 13:11:43

**STEP3:** type (or copy'n'paste) this (if your bootloader date is different to mine, then you'll need to change pieeprom-2020-09-03.bin to the date of your bootloader. format is YYYY/MM/DD)

**cp /lib/firmware/raspberrypi/bootloader/beta/pieeprom-2020-09-03.bin pieeprom.bin**

**STEP4:** type (or copy'n'paste) this .. **rpi-eeprom-config pieeprom.bin > config.txt**

**STEP5:** type (or copy'n'paste) this .. **cat config.txt**

**STEP6:** you should see something like this below ... and what you need to change is DISABLE_HDMI=0 to DISABLE_HDMI=1

```
[all]
BOOT_UART=0
WAKE_ON_GPIO=1
POWER_OFF_ON_HALT=0
DHCP_TIMEOUT=45000
DHCP_REQ_TIMEOUT=4000
TFTP_FILE_TIMEOUT=30000
ENABLE_SELF_UPDATE=1
DISABLE_HDMI=0
BOOT_ORDER=0xf41
```

**STEP7:** type (or copy'n'paste) this .. **sudo nano config.txt**

**STEP8:** edit DISABLE_HDMI=**0** to DISABLE_HDMI=**1** .. then on your keyboard press CTRL O, then ENTER and then CTRL X

**STEP9:** type (or copy'n'paste) this .. **rpi-eeprom-config --out pieeprom-out.bin --config config.txt pieeprom.bin**

**STEP10:** type (or copy'n'paste) this .. **sudo rpi-eeprom-update -d -f ./pieeprom-out.bin**

**STEP11:** You will now see the following message

***BCM2711 detected
Dedicated VL805 EEPROM detected
*** INSTALLING ./pieeprom-out.bin  ***
BOOTFS /boot
EEPROM update pending. Please reboot to apply the update.***

**STEP12:** Last Step .. type **sudo reboot**

When the Raspberry Pi reboots the bootloader Splashscreen is gone.

To re-enable the splashscreen for diagnostics .. just redo all the steps above changing DISABLE_HDMI=**1** back to DISABLE_HDMI=**0**

Comment: On a fully up to date system you can now edit the config with `sudo -E rpi-eeprom-config --edit`. Documented on the page you link to.

Comment: tried that, didn't work (i'm using Retropie 4.7) all i get is .... pi@retropie:/ $ sudo -E rpi-eeprom-config --edit
usage: rpi-eeprom-config [-h] [--config CONFIG] [--out OUT] eeprom
rpi-eeprom-config: error: too few arguments ................ but the guide i posted above, Does work.